# Cannot wait until DOM rendering has finished in Angular/Jasmine unit test

Tags: angular, d3.js, jasmine, vega, angular9

I have an Angular pie chart component built through VegaEmbed (https://github.com/vega/vega-embed) which uses Vega and D3 as underlying graphics dependencies. It renders from supplying a title and some (key, value) pairs. I isolated that component, and modified main.ts to run Jasmine out of Stackblitz to share with you. In this test, I am checking that the pie chart renders indeed SVG `<text>` tags for the values "30%" | "70%" and the legend "Combined CEO/Chair" | "Separate CEO/Chair". However, it seems they run too early and VegaEmbed+Vega+D3 are still busy building that SVG. (I inferred what to test by just looking into the DOM through the Chrome dev tools).

[image]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d3-pie-chart-unit-test

I have tried a range of things: `async`, `FakeAsync` + `tick`, `jasmine.clock`, changing the promises logic in my Angular component, etc... `fixture.whenStable` gets me a step closer but `texts` declared line 50 is still undefined.

I don't know how the internals of Vega, VegaEmbed and D3 are working. If these libraries are not using promises, rather old-fashioned callbacks, then Angular's Zones might fail to wait enough within `async` ?

What confuses me a little is that `console.log(texts);` eventually shows a collection of 4 text SVG element in the console. Yet `console.log(texts.length);` displays 0!

1. How can that be ?
2. How do I get my test code to wait till the moment that D3 has finished drawing the SVG and only run `expect` statements then ?

Comment: I tried another thing, wrapping the `console.log` and `expect` statements within `setTimeout(() => {  ..........  }, 0)` and it makes it all work, even tough I set a timeout of 0 ms... How come ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a good question, I have similar issues with `Ag-Grid` where I have to wait for the rendering or its callbacks to complete before I do assertions and there is no good way like you mentioned with `fakeAsync`, `async/done`, etc. At least none that I have found.

A way I have found is to make a utility function like so:

```
import { interval } from 'rxjs';
.....
export const waitUntil = async (untilTruthy: Function): Promise<boolean> => {
  while (!untilTruthy()) {
    // older API
    // await interval(25).pipe(take(1)).toPromise();
    // newer API
    await firstValueFrom(interval(25));
  }
  return Promise.resolve(true);
};
```

`waitUntil` will keep looping every 25ms until the callback function supplied is truthy. The amount of time is up to you.

So in your tests, you can do something like:

```
it('should render the chart', async () => {
  // make your arrangements
  // do your action
  fixture.detectChanges();
  // wait for promises to resolve (optional)
  await fixture.whenStable();
  await waitUntil(() => /* put a condition here that will resolve to a truthy value 
  at a later time where the rest of the assertions rely on 
  it such as the graph being present with its labels*/);
  // the rest of your assertions of what should be there what should not
});
```

You mention `setTimeout` working with a value of 0. This works because we are putting what's inside of the `setTimeout` at the end of the call stack queue because it runs asynchronously. Doing it this way is still good but I like how the tests read with the `waitUntil` approach.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, and sharing a nice alternative!