# Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value'). Angular/Jasmine Issue with component template tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine

I have next test for a compoent:

[image]

[image]

The test responses with output: "Cannot set properties of null (setting 'value')"
But sometimes it works. The problem is that "memberMessage" is null at that time when test tries to set a value. What is the possible way to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Next time, try not to paste an image and paste the code itself.

This won't be a complete answer but it should help you debug

```
 it('changes to last value if invalid', async () => {
   // wait for promises to complete - (1)
   await fixture.whenStable();
   // call fixture.detectChanges() again after promises - (2)
   fixture.detectChanges()
   const memberMessage = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#mat-input-2');
   console.log({ memberMessage }); // ensure this is not null
 });
```

If the above does not work, try using a `waitUntil` utility from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60489120/7365461).

```
it('changes to last value if invalid', async () => {
  // it will waitUntil the below function returns true
  await waitUntil(() => !!fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#mat-input-2'));
  const memberMessage = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#mat-input-2');
  console.log({ memberMessage }); // should hopefully not be null now
});
```