# How to unit test Angular service with time-consuming async method?

Tags: angular, testing, jasmine

I have a service with a time-consuming async operation:

```ts
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService{

public timeConsumingMethod() {
      setTimeout(() => someTimeConsumingMethod()});
}
private someTimeConsumingMethod(){}
}
```

and I would like to write a test (using Jasmine) that will wait until the code in `setTimeout` method has finished processing (the macro task queue will be empty):

```ts
describe('TestService', () => {
  let service: TestService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(TestService);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    service.timeConsumingMethod();
    //expect(result_of_timeConsumingMethod).toBe(some_result);
  });
});
```

Unfortunately I cannot make it work.

- `fakeAsync` is not suitable because it only allows to move time forward or empty/discard task queue, but it does not have a tool to "wait" for macro task to finish.
- `async`/`await` is also not suitable because `timeConsumingMethod` is synchronous (despite it triggering an async task in `setTimeout`).
- I cannot use `waitForAsync` because there is no tool to wait for task (something like `fixture.whenStable()` would be suitable but there is no such tool for Angular services, fixture works only for components).

In the end I'm struggling between: "1 timer(s) still in the queue" error or error that says that my test expectation is not met.

The only solution that works is to use Jasmine's `done` callback and wait a fixed number of seconds:

```ts
  it('should be created', () => {
    service.timeConsumingMethod();
    setTimeout(()=>{
       //expect(result_of_timeConsumingMethod).toBe(some_result);
       done();
     }, 60000);
  });
```

but it is a poor solution; in my real example I do not know how many seconds I should wait.

**Edit:**

Another approach is to change service method to return observable which will inform about ends of time-consuming processing:

```ts
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TestService {

    public timeConsumingMethod(): Observable<boolean> {
        const isDone$ = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
        setTimeout(() => {
            try {
                this.someTimeConsumingMethod();
            }
            finally {
                isDone$.next(true);
                isDone$.complete();
            }
        });
        return isDone$.asObservable();
    }
    private someTimeConsumingMethod() { }
}
```

and then use `async/await` in the test method:

```ts
describe('TestService', () => {
  let service: TestService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(TestService);
  });

  it('should be created', async () => {
    await service.timeConsumingMethod().toPromise();
    //expect(result_of_timeConsumingMethod).toBe(some_result);
  });
});
```

But I am still not satisfied with this, because it drives to application code change. Code was simpler and did what it should before. Now only because of need of writing test code became much complicated.

Comment: What does `someTimeConsumingMethod` **do**? From the point of view of testing the behaviour, _that's_ what you should be waiting for.

Comment: If your method does something asynchronous, you need to split that asynchronous behaviour into a separate method which returns an Observable that emits when the async test is done. When something like this seems hard to test, it's generally that your code is poorly structured.

Comment: @jonrsharpe It should test that some inner method from time-consuming processing was invoked, so i am waiting to check if that method was called which indicates that test is ok. ps. thanks for editing post

Comment: @WillAlexander i edited original post inspired by Your sugestion, but as i wrote, i'm not still satisfied, because my case is to test method which works in "fire and forget" manner, so adding any returns force me to change this manner.

Comment: "invoke a method" isn't what it's _for_, unless that's a collaborator - what is the _actual work_ that you're waiting on? Is there a side effect? And I'd argue that a more testable design is a better idea, but if `someTimeConsumingMethod` is blocking as your example implies, you can't help but "wait" for it anyway.

Comment: Actual work - it is rendering page to canvas and converting it to pdf file, the end of a process is "download file" popup window in browser.

Comment: If your time consuming method is long but synchronous, you don't have to wait for it: its result is ready by the time JS runs the next line.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how long to wait, I think you can use `async/await` with a helper utility function of `waitUntil`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60489120/7365461) answer on how to implement the `waitUntil` utility function.

```
it('should be created', async () => {
    service.timeConsumingMethod();
    // wait until what is returned from the lamda function returns true
    await waitUntil(() => result_of_timeConsumingMethod === some_result);
    // make your assertion
    expect(result_of_timeConsumingMethod).toBe(some_result);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, this indeed is a some way to solve that in a case that time-consuming method will change state of application and we have a way to check it in lambda You mentioned. Unfortunatelly in my case the processing ends with browser request to download file i do not know how to create lambda `() => result_of_timeConsumingMethod === some_result` that will check it. Currently as a `result_of_timeConsumingMethod` i use `expect(service['some inner method name']).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `flush()` which:

> Flushes any pending microtasks and simulates the asynchronous passage of time for the timers in the fakeAsync zone by draining the macrotask queue until it is empty ([doc](https://angular.io/api/core/testing/flush))

```
describe('TestService', () => {
  let service: TestService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({});
    service = TestBed.inject(TestService);
  });

  it('should be created', fakeAsync (() => {
    service.timeConsumingMethod();

    // this will make sure all asynchronous operations are completed
    // so the following expect statements can be executed safely on the result of this operation.
    flush();  

    expect(result_of_timeConsumingMethod).toBe(some_result);
  }));
});
```