# AgGrid selectors always return null / no elements even when table correctly renders

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, ag-grid

I have an ag grid:

```
<app-my-component>
  <ag-grid-angular
    [gridOptions]="gridOptions"
    (gridReady)="setGridReady()">
  </ag-grid-angular>
</app-my-component>
```

And in my Karma-Jasmine tests, I am testing that the table renders on the page:

```
it('Should render data table', async(() => { 

  // Wait for ag grid to render rows
  fixture.detectChanges();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    const agGrid = element.query(By.css('ag-grid-angular'));
    expect(agGrid).toBeTruthy();
  });

}));
```

So far so good. everything works. I can see the table rendered on the page on chrome when karma runs (I haven't removed the element in `afterEach` so I can debug)

Now, I'm trying to test that the number of rows match the mockData that I've got. I can see the three rows that's rendered on the page.

```
it('Should display all three rows from mock data', async(() => {

  // Wait for ag grid to render rows
  fixture.detectChanges();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    let rows = element.queryAll(By.css('.my-custom-class'));
    expect(rows.length).toBe(3);
  });

}));
```

This test, however, fails. `.my-custom-class` selector always seems to return `null`. No worries, maybe I'm mistyping the class or something, or so I thought.
I opened up the developer console and typed in `$('.my-custom-class')`. To my surprise, this returns `null` as well!

If I try to select any cell value elements with `$('.ag-cell-value')`, that's null as well.

But I can see all the data and the table on the page! so I right click on the table and inspect element > check for the class...
and try `$('.my-custom-class')` - Now it returns 3 elements! `$('.ag-cell-value')` works as expected as well!

What's happening here? Why can't I select the elements with css selector before I expand the DOM in html, and more importantly,
how do I select and test for my three rows in my unit test please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I was using `ag-grid`, I faced the same issue. It seems like it renders on its own and we have no control of when the rendering is done.

What I did to circumvent this was create a `waitUntil` utility function outlined here: [Cannot wait until DOM rendering has finished in Angular/Jasmine unit test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60487439/cannot-wait-until-dom-rendering-has-finished-in-angular-jasmine-unit-test/60489120#60489120)

With the wait until, what you can maybe do is:

```
import { waitUntil } from './where/waitUntil/is';
....
it('should display all three rows from mock data', async () => {
  fixture.detectChanges();

  await fixture.whenStable();
  
  // Basically, in this waitUntil, wait until everything in AgGrid is painted
  // before moving on with your test. The waitUntil has to return true before
  // it can proceed to the next line.
  await waitUntil(() => { 
     const rows = appElement.queryAll(By.css('.my-custom-class'));
     return rows.length === 3; 
  });
  
  // do other expectations
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for that. I just tried it and it seems to wait for ever and eventually my karma shuts down the browser and/or throws a `exceeded call stack` or something weird. I also looked at the ag grid docs and tried things from here: https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/testing/ - My grid says it's ready, I can even see the grid and data, just that the debugElement isn't able to find it (same with jquery on dev console. it's strange!)

Comment: Hello, Yes, you're right, it is strange. I remember I had difficulty testing the view of Ag Grid as well.