# Test values with cellRenderer in Ag Grid in Angular and Jest

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

My problem is I need to test the actual values shown in an Ag Grid table column. These values have a cellRenderer attached to format them based on specific conditions.

In my Jest test, I've tried a lot of different approaches:

- Using `fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css([`*`selector`*`]))`, where [*selector*] has been `[col-id="amount"]`, `.currencyFormat`, `lib-frm-result-indicator-cell-renderer`... Nothing worked (0 elements). To query values without cellRenderer the expected was returned. Note that DOM hierarchy for my cellRenderer value is like this: [image: List item]
- Trying to access method `getCellRendererInstances()`. I've seen [in this](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/component-cell-renderer/#reference-rendering-getCellRendererInstances) that this method returns the cellRenderers used, and I tried it outside the test environment with successful results. In my Jest test `component.gridOptions.api` or `component.gridApi` are both `undefined`. I've to wait until `gridReady` event is fired: I've tried things like next:

```js
// 1. 
it('cellRenderer is defined', waitForAsync(() => {
  fixture.detectChanges();
  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    expect(component.gridOptions.api).toBeDefined();
  })
}))
```

On this attempt, `whenStable()` is running real code execution, which causes a lot of errors because not all the code is mocked (I'd have to mock such a lot of things to really run my TS file).

```js
// 2.
it('cellRenderer is defined', (done) => {
  component.gridOptions.onGridReady = () => {
    fixture.detectChanges(),
    const cellRenderer = component.gridOptions.api.getCellRendererInstances();
    done();
  }
  
  component.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
    { field: 'name' },
    { field: 'amount', cellRenderer: ResultIndicatorCellRendererComonent }
  ];
  fixture.detectChanges();
)
```

On the second attempt, a timeout error is coming out.

So, what's the approach to get this? Am I missing something here? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's possible, I remember I had a lot of issues like you when I was attempting to unit test components with `AG-Grid`. It seems like `AG-Grid` paints on its own and no amount of `tick`, `whenStable`, `flush`, etc. will do the trick because we don't have control of when it is done rendering.

I would try with a `setTimeout` to see if it fixes the issue:

```
// do everything to make the grid be painted the way you would like
setTimeout(() => {
  const columns = fixture.debugElement.queryAll(By.css('[col-id="amount"]'));
  expect(columns).toBeTruthy();
  done();
}, 2_000);
```

If the `setTimeout` works, it might be preferable to make a `waitUntilTruthy` utility function as outlined here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60489120/7365461.

Then you can do:

```
// Set up everything the way you would like
await waitUntilTruthy(() => /* Some condition that will return true at a later point in time related to the chart */);
// Now that the previous condition is truthy, it means we made it to a checkpoint.
// Do the remaining of your assertions
```